# PHP check if time range is in a time range

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a time bounded to someone into the database. 
For example: Peter 13:00 - 19:00

Peter told us he can't work from 18:00 - 22:00. (This is located in the database).

so the time 13:00 - 19:00 can't be inserted into the database because the end time (19:00) is within the timerange 18:00 - 22:00.

How to check  this?

I've tried several things but I dont know how to do it right.

Got this right now

```
$van_besch = '18:00';
$tot_besch = '22:00';

$van = '13:00';
$tot = '19:00';

if (($van_besch >= $van) && ($tot_besch <= $tot)) {
        $error ='<font color="red">Time '.$van_besch.' - '.$tot_besch.' Not available</font>';
    }
```

This won't work.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is this in a database or just PHP?

Comment: Actually the values will be from the database. But I replaced them with known variables. So This is PHP

Comment: first of all, have you ensured that the datetime format that you're using on your code is the same format that you use in your database? if it's already the same, can you please inform us the format?

Comment: You should be able to construct the query to check an employee's workable hours and if there is an overlap don't insert.

Comment: its not a format its just H:i . hours and minutes. Its not a datetime.
But I mean, Iam able to check 18:00 >= 19:00. This will return false.
But something like this must be done with the 2 time ranges.
If an employee blocks the hours 13:00 - 22:00. And the administrator wants to schedule the employee from 12:00 - 15:00. It shouldn't be possible because 15:00 > 13:00.

Comment: what about shifts that straddle a day break? `22:00-02:00`? your code needs to handle such situations as well..

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two cases you have to check:

1. `$van` is equal or between `$van_besch` and `$tot_besch`
2. `$tot` is equal or between `$van_besch` and `$tot_besch`

if `$van` and `$tot` are both between `$van_besch` and `$tot_besch` both cases are true.

Further more you need to handle shifts that straddle a day break e.g. 17:00 - 02:00. Another problem is you need to handle is 20:00 - 0:00, since 0:00 is smaller than 20:00.

Therefore we project the real time to our own time format. 
That means 17:00 - 02:00 will become 17:00 - 26:00. Note that we need to do this for both `$van_besch` - `$tot_besch` and `$van` - `$tot$`.

In code that would look be something like:

```
if ($tot < $van){
   $tot = 24:00 - $van + $tot;
}

if ($tot_besch < $van_besch){
   $tot = 24:00 - $van + $tot;
}

if (($van >= $van_besch) && ($van <= $tot_besch) ) || (($tot >= $tot_besch) && ($tot <= $tot_besch)){
 ... Peter is not available ... 
}
```

Comment: You can actually combine both logics into one statement. `$van <= $tot_besch && $tot >= $van_besch`.  But you'll want to also be sure in all cases that `$van <= $tot` and `$van_besch <= $tot_besch`.  But basically this will cover the time slot falling anywhere between, overlapping at the end, or overlapping at the start, in one short comparison.

Comment: @squeegy This was exactly the answer I needed.  This works perfectly! It only won't work for 17.00 - 02.00 for example.  Need to figure something out for. That

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird Check out my answer bellow.  I talk about that and splitting it into two comparisons, dividing at midnight, that or a super cheap way would be to add 24 hours to the end time so it would be `17:00 - 26:00` and just make sure you do the same to your other time if it crosses midnight.

Comment: @squeegy seems legit. But I dont understand your method. I tried it with your tables and your queries, but it will return me 1 anyway and anyhow.

Comment: @Stan van der Avoird does my edited solution work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is better you convert them and compare using `strtotime`. Something like this would work for you:

```
$van_besch = '18:00';
$tot_besch = '22:00';

$van = '13:00';
$tot = '19:00';

if (strtotime($van) < strtotime($van_besch) || strtotime($tot ) > strtotime($tot_besch)) {
   //code goes here
}
```

Comment: Actually the best would be to use `DateTime` as it considers timezones and DST.

Comment: yes, something like this `$exampleTime=new DateTime($van)` would do the trick and then compare them.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this in an SQL query for sure.  And if you're just storing time, it would be best to do it as an int `0000 - 2359`.

So our table would look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE off_time (
  id int(12) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  employee int(12) NOT NULL,
  start_time smallInt(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  end_time smallInt(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

We're storing a start and end time to create a block of time that they don't work.  Obviously in your code it's important that you makes sure these blocks make sense and start_time <= end_time.

Now we can query.

```
// Here we use just < and > but you can make them <= and >= if you don't want time slots to possibly overlap start/end times.
SELECT ot.id, IF( 1300 < ot.end_time AND 1900 > ot.start_time, 1, 0) AS blocked
FROM off_time as ot
WHERE ot.employee = 1;
```

You will get a table back where each row will have the `id` of the blocked time slot, and a `blocked` column with 1 meaning it's blocked and 0 meaning it's not.  So if any of the entries are 1, then you know your time is blocked out.  Doing it this way is also handy because you can also relate a reasons table, and be able to respond with a reason.  `LEFT JOIN time_off_reasons as r on r.id = ot.id`

If you want to be specific with dates.  Just store `timestamp` for start and end times.  The comparison will be the same, just with timestamps instead.

**EDIT**
Marc B. made a good point in the comments about time blocks that stretch over the midnight mark i.e. 2200 - 0200.  With my method you would want to make sure you split those apart as separate entries.

So `INSERT INTO off_time (start_time, end_time) VALUES(2200, 2400)(0000,0200)`

This will still work as expected.  But you'll just have two entries for 1 time off block, which might be annoying, but still easier than writing extra code to compensate for the logic.